# How to make gprof report in nanosecond?

Tags: c++, gprof

I'm trying to profile my C++ application, using gprof I would like to calculate function execution time. However in case some functions run faster than 0.01s it's reported on gprof with value 0.00. How can I change the report time of gprof to nanosecond?

Thanks for your advices.

```
    Flat profile:

    Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
     no time accumulated

      %   cumulative   self              self     total           
     time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    
      0.00      0.00     0.00        3     0.00     0.00  access_counter
      0.00      0.00     0.00        2     0.00     0.00  get_counter
      0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  start_counter

Copyright (C) 2012-2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
notice and this notice are preserved.

.....

             Call graph (explanation follows)


granularity: each sample hit covers 2 byte(s) no time propagated

index % time    self  children    called     name
                0.00    0.00       1/3           start_counter [3]
                0.00    0.00       2/3           get_counter [2]
[1]      0.0    0.00    0.00       3         access_counter [1]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       2/2           main [9]
[2]      0.0    0.00    0.00       2         get_counter [2]
                0.00    0.00       2/3           access_counter [1]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [9]
[3]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         start_counter [3]
                0.00    0.00       1/3           access_counter [1]
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I don't know for sure but I assume gprof is reporting in the same resolution that it records samples in. To get around this issue, use a longer running test case.

Comment: I believe there is a way to setting the report time resolution, maybe by an gprof option or sth else. Actually most of functions in real time applications run very, very fast when handling thousand of messages. Must have some ways to profiling them!

Answer (score 2):

> How to make gprof report in nanosecond?

The timing data in gprof is based on sampling, and nanosecond-resolution sampling is impractical.

You can't extract the instruction pointer on *every* instruction of a running program, and if you could, it would anyway alter performance so much the measurement might be meaningless.

If you don't care about *actual* runtime (which can't be measured at this resolution without changing it), you can always just run [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual.html)'s `callgrind` or `cachegrind` tools to literally count the number of instructions.

> Actually most of functions in real time applications run very, very fast when handling thousand of messages. Must have some ways to profiling them!

For profiling things that are too fast to be usefully detected by sampling, your options are:

1. benchmark it in isolation and hope the performance doesn't change too much in a whole-program context

   this means running it enough times in a loop that the total latency is accurately measurable, such as with [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark)
2. add your own instrumentation to record high-resolution timestamps on entry and exit (although this has a non-trivial cost for a function that's already very fast)
3. instrument and/or sample a higher-level function that calls the fast function lots of times
4. ... some other combinations of the above ...

FWIW I've written plenty of latency-critical code, and a combination of micro (or I guess nano) benchmarks and whole-program latency stats for regression testing on canned data have generally been enough.

When you still can't figure out where your time is going, you may also need to start collecting hardware performance counters to compare things like cache miss and branch mis-prediction rates.

Answer (score 1):

To my understandings, it depends on how frequent the profiling data was recorded. The profiling process is controlled by the `__moncontrol` function in glibc [[1](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.29/source/gmon/gmon.c#L107)], in which it will call `__profil` to initiate a timer [[2](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.29/source/sysdeps/posix/profil.c#L114)]. What we really care about here is the interval of the timer, which is determined by

```c
timer.it_value.tv_usec = 1000000 / __profile_frequency ();
```

where `__profile_frequency()` will try to get the smallest granularity if possible. So to conclude, it is machine dependent. Furthermore, the [gprof manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gprof-2.9.1/html_chapter/gprof_9.html) stated that it's typically around 10 ms, so I think it is unlikely if not impossible that we can track down to nanoseconds:

> Typically the program counter is looked at around 100 times per second of run time, but the exact frequency may vary from system to system.

Reference: https://blog.csdn.net/absurd/article/details/1477532